# Tabs when set one to active turn all false alogrithim Meteor React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I am trying to:
Make a tab be active and turn off all the other ones.
Currently I only have it working where it will turn off and on one at a time.

I a trying to figure out how I can do this. 
I was thinking is there a way to pass in the parent component to the function and then be able to access the className property of all its children??
Currently I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export default class TestContainer extends React.Component{


        setActive(event){
           event.preventDefault();

           //getting id from component
           let isActive = event.target.id;


           if(event.currentTarget.className === "list-group-item text-center active"){
                   event.currentTarget.className = "list-group-item text-center";
           } else if(event.currentTarget.className === "list-group-item text-center") {
                   event.currentTarget.className = "list-group-item text-center active";
           }

        }



        render(){   




         return (                               

                <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 bhoechie-tab-container    scroll-y">
                        <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 bhoechie-tab-menu">
                                <div className="list-group">
                                        <a href="#" onClick={this.setActive} id="eyes" className="list-group-item text-center active">
                                                <h4 className="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></h4><br/>1
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" onClick={this.setActive} id="hair" className="list-group-item text-center">
                                                <h4 className="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></h4><br/>2
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" onClick={this.setActive} id="mouth" className="list-group-item text-center">
                                                <h4 className="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></h4><br/>3
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" onClick={this.setActive} id="clothing" className="list-group-item text-center">
                                                <h4 className="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></h4><br/>4
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" onClick={this.setActive} id="props" className="list-group-item text-center">
                                                <h4 className="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></h4><br/>5
                                        </a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

By trying to change the state of your elements outside of the `render()` method, you're fighting against the strengths of React's rendering engine.  Use state, either internal to the component or provided via props/context (preferably props), to determine which tab should be rendered with `active` in its className.

When you respond to a click, change the state and let React re-render the component based on the new state.

For the limited example provided here, I'd recommend storing the ID of the active element internally in the component's state.

```
export default class TestContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeTab: this.props.activeTab || 'eyes'
    };
  }

  setActive(event) {
    this.setState({ activeTab: event.target.id });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeTab } = this.state;
    const tabClassName = "list-group-item text-center";
    const eyesTabClassName = tabClassName + (activeTab === 'eyes' ? ' active' : '');

    ...

              <a href="#" onClick={this.setActive} id="eyes" className={eyesTabClassName}>

    ...

  }
}
```

This is a rough, unoptimized solution, but it should get the idea across.  When you call `this.setState`, React responds by marking the component as needing to be re-rendered.  The `render()` method will automatically be called and thus all of your JSX will be re-evaluated and re-rendered.  React will then look at the difference between what it just produced and what is already in the virtual DOM and merge in your changes.

This means that whichever tab was previously rendered with "active" in its className will be re-rendered.  If it's no longer active, your render code would not have concatenated the active class into that tab's className.  Further, whichever class is active will now have its className appended with "active".

**TL;DR**

Don't manipulate the DOM in your event handlers.  Manipulate state and let React work its magic by re-rendering with your new state.